# Using OpenCV with OpenCL on Intel UHD Graphics 630 along with nvidia GPU

Tags: opencv, opencl

I currently have a program running all the time using my Nvidia GPU.
I would like to run another one aside, which would use OpenCV with OpenCL.
I use Ubuntu 18.04 and my processor is an Intel i7-9750H (with UHD Graphics 630).

I run this C++ code to detect the available devices:

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>


int main()
{
    cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);
    if (!cv::ocl::haveOpenCL())
    {
        std::cout << "OpenCL is not available..." << std::endl;
        //return;
    }

    cv::ocl::Context context;
    if (!context.create(cv::ocl::Device::TYPE_ALL))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed creating the context..." << std::endl;
        //return;
    }

    std::cout << context.ndevices() << " GPU devices are detected." << std::endl; //This bit provides an overview of the OpenCL devices you have in your computer
    for (int i = 0; i < context.ndevices(); i++)
    {
        cv::ocl::Device device = context.device(i);
        std::cout << "name:              " << device.name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "available:         " << device.available() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "imageSupport:      " << device.imageSupport() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "OpenCL_C_Version:  " << device.OpenCL_C_Version() << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
1 GPU devices are detected.
name:              GeForce RTX 2060
available:         1
imageSupport:      1
OpenCL_C_Version:  OpenCL C 1.2
```

So the issue is that my integrated intel GPU isn't detected.

I installed ocl-icd-opencl-dev and "Compute runtime" (NEO) : https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime
but it didn't change anything.

Here's the ouput of `clinfo`:

```
Number of platforms                               3
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 11.0.228
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 3.0 
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_fp16 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_icd cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_required_subgroup_size cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_khr_spir cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_driver_diagnostics cl_khr_priority_hints cl_khr_throttle_hints cl_khr_create_command_queue cl_intel_subgroups_char cl_intel_subgroups_long cl_khr_il_program cl_intel_mem_force_host_memory cl_khr_subgroup_extended_types cl_khr_subgroup_non_uniform_vote cl_khr_subgroup_ballot cl_khr_subgroup_non_uniform_arithmetic cl_khr_subgroup_shuffle cl_khr_subgroup_shuffle_relative cl_khr_subgroup_clustered_reduce cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_subgroups cl_intel_spirv_device_side_avc_motion_estimation cl_intel_spirv_media_block_io cl_intel_spirv_subgroups cl_khr_spirv_no_integer_wrap_decoration cl_intel_unified_shared_memory_preview cl_khr_mipmap_image cl_khr_mipmap_image_writes cl_intel_planar_yuv cl_intel_packed_yuv cl_intel_motion_estimation cl_intel_device_side_avc_motion_estimation cl_intel_advanced_motion_estimation cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_intel_media_block_io cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_va_api_media_sharing 
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns
  Platform Extensions function suffix             INTEL

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 LINUX
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_intel_vec_len_hint 
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns
  Platform Extensions function suffix             INTEL

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     GeForce RTX 2060
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  450.80.02
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Topology (NV)                            PCI-E, 01:00.0
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               30
  Max clock frequency                             1200MHz
  Compute Capability (NV)                         7.5
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1024x64
  Max work group size                             1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Warp size (NV)                                  32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 1       
    short                                                1 / 1       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              6222839808 (5.795GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           1555709952 (1.449GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Integrated memory (NV)                          No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       4096 bits (512 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        983040 (960KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   128 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             32
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            268435456 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             32768x32768 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             16384x16384x16384 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 256
    Max number of write image args                32
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               49152 (48KiB)
  Registers per block (NV)                        65536
  Max number of constant args                     9
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     4352 (4.25KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1000ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Kernel execution timeout (NV)                 Yes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution (NV)       Yes
    Number of async copy engines                  3
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Gen9 HD Graphics NEO
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 3.0 NEO 
  Driver Version                                  20.41.18123
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 3.0 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               24
  Max clock frequency                             1150MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     0
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Max sub-groups per work group                   32
  Sub-group sizes (Intel)                         8, 16, 32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 8 / 8        (cl_khr_fp16)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (cl_khr_fp16)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              20044763136 (18.67GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           4294959104 (4GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   No
    Fine-grained system sharing                   No
    Atomics                                       No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics                 
    SVM                                           64 bytes
    Global                                        64 bytes
    Local                                         64 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    65536 (64KiB)
  Preferred total size of global vars             4294959104 (4GiB)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        524288 (512KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            268434944 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   4 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          4 pixels
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max planar YUV image size                     16384x16352 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             16384x16384x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                128
    Max number of read/write image args           128
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    1
  Max pipe packet size                            1024
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               65536 (64KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max constant buffer size                        4294959104 (4GiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     2048 (2KiB)
  Queue properties (on host)                      
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Queue properties (on device)                    
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                131072 (128KiB)
    Max size                                      67108864 (64MiB)
  Max queues on device                            1
  Max events on device                            1024
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      83ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Sub-group independent forward progress        Yes
    IL version                                    SPIR-V_1.2 
    SPIR versions                                 1.2 
  printf() buffer size                            4194304 (4MiB)
  Built-in kernels                                block_motion_estimate_intel;block_advanced_motion_estimate_check_intel;block_advanced_motion_estimate_bidirectional_check_intel;
  Motion Estimation accelerator version (Intel)   2
    Device-side AVC Motion Estimation version     1
      Supports texture sampler use                Yes
      Supports preemption                         No
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_fp16 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_icd cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_required_subgroup_size cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_khr_spir cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_driver_diagnostics cl_khr_priority_hints cl_khr_throttle_hints cl_khr_create_command_queue cl_intel_subgroups_char cl_intel_subgroups_long cl_khr_il_program cl_intel_mem_force_host_memory cl_khr_subgroup_extended_types cl_khr_subgroup_non_uniform_vote cl_khr_subgroup_ballot cl_khr_subgroup_non_uniform_arithmetic cl_khr_subgroup_shuffle cl_khr_subgroup_shuffle_relative cl_khr_subgroup_clustered_reduce cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_subgroups cl_intel_spirv_device_side_avc_motion_estimation cl_intel_spirv_media_block_io cl_intel_spirv_subgroups cl_khr_spirv_no_integer_wrap_decoration cl_intel_unified_shared_memory_preview cl_khr_mipmap_image cl_khr_mipmap_image_writes cl_intel_planar_yuv cl_intel_packed_yuv cl_intel_motion_estimation cl_intel_device_side_avc_motion_estimation cl_intel_advanced_motion_estimation cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_intel_media_block_io cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_va_api_media_sharing 

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.1 (Build 0)
  Driver Version                                  18.1.0.0920
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0 
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               12
  Max clock frequency                             2600MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     12
    Supported partition types                     by counts, equally, by names (Intel)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             8192x8192x8192
  Max work group size                             8192
  Preferred work group size multiple              128
  Max sub-groups per work group                   1
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 32      
    short                                                1 / 16      
    int                                                  1 / 8       
    long                                                 1 / 4       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 8       
    double                                               1 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              25055956992 (23.34GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           6263989248 (5.834GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   Yes
    Fine-grained system sharing                   Yes
    Atomics                                       Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics                 
    SVM                                           64 bytes
    Global                                        64 bytes
    Local                                         0 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    65536 (64KiB)
  Preferred total size of global vars             65536 (64KiB)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        262144 (256KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             480
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            391499328 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   64 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          64 pixels
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 480
    Max number of write image args                480
    Max number of read/write image args           480
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    21845
  Max pipe packet size                            1024
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     480
  Max constant buffer size                        131072 (128KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     3840 (3.75KiB)
  Queue properties (on host)                      
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Local thread execution (Intel)                Yes
  Queue properties (on device)                    
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                4294967295 (4GiB)
    Max size                                      4294967295 (4GiB)
  Max queues on device                            4294967295
  Max events on device                            4294967295
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    Sub-group independent forward progress        No
    IL version                                    SPIR-V_1.0
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_intel_vec_len_hint 

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [NV]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  Invalid device type for platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform
    NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 2.0,
        but some installed platforms support OpenCL 3.0.
        Programs using 3.0 features may crash
        or behave unexepectedly
```

I guess my question is:

1. Is it possible to run one code on my Nvidia GPU and another one on my Intel UHD Graphics ?
2. If it is, why can't I see Intel UHD Graphics in my C++ code's output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat messy situation. There is a difference between using multiple OpenCL devices from a single platform and different platforms.

**Question 2:** Each OpenCL implementation/SDK/Runtime you install will show up as a platform. The [context class of OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d1/d45/classcv_1_1ocl_1_1Context.html#a1db64b0cb4055c0a3fbeb51fd8682bfa) is bound to a single platform and can only work with the corresponding devices. The constructor only allows to specify a device type, so it probably queries OpenCL and uses the first platform with that device type (or just the first). **That's why OpenCV only shows the Nvidia device.**

**Question 1:** Creating another context reflecting the Intel platform **would be possible** by using the OpenCL API directly and then calling OpenCV's `fromHandle()` or `fromDevice()` functions to create the OpenCV Context object (the clinfo source is an example for the required code). **But**, using different platforms means linking to different OpenCL libraries (indirectly at runtime through the compile-time linked libOpenCL). I.e. memory objects, etc. cannot be shared between the different contexts, so practical usability is rather limited unless you have independent problems that you'd like to compute in parallel on both devices.

**Bonus:**
Your `clinfo` output shows 3 platforms (Nvidia OpenCL 1.2, Intel GPU OpenCL 3.0, Intel CPU OpenCL 2.1), and you see the warning:

```
NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 2.0,
        but some installed platforms support OpenCL 3.0.
        Programs using 3.0 features may crash
        or behave unexepectedly
```

With 3 OpenCL implementations installed, you will end up with one `/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so` in your system, while every implementation installed this file, possibly overwriting an existing one. So you end up with the one of the last installed OpenCL implementation, which is not necessarily a problem, but can be with the 3 different major versions. The `libOpenCL.so` is just a shallow loader (ICD loader in OpenCL terms) that looks into `/etc/OpenCL/vendors` where there is a `*.icd` (installable client driver) file for every installed OpenCL implementation. These are simple text files containing the actual OpenCL library (i.e. platform) of a certain vendor, which will be loaded at runtime.

You are probably using the `libOpenCL.so` for the Intel GPU SDK which has OpenCL 3.0 support. Depending on the `libOpenCL.so`, or loader, you end up using, the platform order might be different, and you could end up having a different platform/device in your application. If you wanted to force your application to use another platform without fiddling with the OpenCL API directly, you could also work around the loader at link time, by **not linking against `/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so`, but the library listed in the `*.icd*` file** directly. An application linked like that will only show that one corresponding platform and its devices. So by directly linking to the Intel GPU library, your application will use that one instead of the Nvidia GPU. The binary won't be suited for packaging though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the first two points are clear for me, but for the bonus, I don't understand what you mean by linking against .icd files directly, can these be considered as .so ?

Comment: The *.icd file is a text file, which contains the name of the .so file.

Answer (score 0):

I also try some ways...I find out that we should first build opencv with the intel opencl support(the nvidia opencl support is included when build with cuda),so we have to install the intel opencl sdk.Then set an envionment variable OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE=Intel:GPU:1(for dual GPU platform like laptop,0 usually stand for the discrete GPU and 1 stand for the Integrated GPU).The envionment variable layout is like:

```
  // Layout: <Platform>:<CPU|GPU|ACCELERATOR|nothing=GPU/CPU>:<deviceName>
  // Sample: AMD:GPU:
  // Sample: AMD:GPU:Tahiti
  // Sample: :GPU|CPU: = '' = ':' = '::'
```

From modules\core\src\ocl.cpp function:parseOpenCLDeviceConfiguration